# jQuery - Show Description on Hover - Dynamic Content

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to toggle a description on hover of dynamic bootstrap cards. I'm trying to trigger the `.card-description` class to show when hovered *of the current hovered item*.

At this moment it toggles *all* descriptions of all cards.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".frontpage-fluid .card", function() {
    $(".frontpage-fluid .card .card-description").show();
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".frontpage-fluid .card", function() {
    $(".frontpage-fluid .card .card-description").hide();
});
```

How can I make it so it only toggles the description of the current hovered item?

PS: Using jQuery `.hover` will not work on dynamic content

Comment: It would be helpful to see a relevant sample from your HTML.  Please edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing global lookups, rather than finding the elements you want contextually.

```
$(".card-description", this).show();
//or
$(this).find(".card-description").show();
```

This will find the card description only inside the element that the event happened on.

As a side note to this, I should mention that you could do this with a couple CSS rules, and forgo the javascript all together.

```
.frontpage-fluid .card .card-description { display: none; }
.frontpage-fluid .card:hover .card-description { display: inherit; }
```

Comment: @J.Doe  also included a suggestion about some CSS rules.